# Binary-only include Eclipse Public License: EPL 1.0 into a Apache 2.0 project

Tags: apache-2.0, epl

I am planning to binary-include(only to package it into release in build, not include it in the source) an EPL v1.0 library in my Apache 2.0 project.

What I will do are:

- ensure the lib is not code/binary placed in source code
- clarify that in the released package, this lib is included and the lib is under EPL v1.0
- license the project in Apache 2.0

Is this correct? If possible, could I have any examples(projects) on doing so to be referred :).

Thanks a lot!

ref:

- [Using EPL 2.0 library as a node module in APL 2.0 project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12445/using-epl-2-0-library-as-a-node-module-in-apl-2-0-project)
- https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#category-b
- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2552981/44683095-98ee0080-aa45-11e8-8970-cfb0bc51f240.png

Comment: The linked question is clear that "*you cannot re-license unmodified EPL-ed code under the Apache 2 license. However, you can very well have them side-by-side in your project*".  Does this not answer your question?  If not, what uncertainty remains?

Comment: Thanks, @MadHatter :). The main uncertainty for me was my case is for EPL v1 rather than v2. I will put it side-by-side and cite it in a license.[md|txt] file.

Comment: Thank you for your courteous reponse!  The v1/v2 issue seems a legitimate one to me, although I think the linked answer doesn't depend on anything v2-specific in its analysis, and so would still apply.  Are you happy that your question has been answered, and if so, should I close this a a duplicate of the linked one?

Comment: Dear @MadHatter,
Thanks :) I am good with closing it with duplicated being marked, also your comment emphasizing the first ref is not v2-specific will help newcomers know the answer clearly, too.